# Is there a GearmanProvider for Silex?

Tags: silex, gearman

I am looking for a provider thats gives me the ability to use Gearman with my Silex application.

I have found https://github.com/skeetr/silex but it seems that this provider is too old and it uses pecl_http instead of curl.

Does anyone know a better GearmanProvider for Silex? Can a use a

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research i have used [Skeetr/Silex](https://github.com/skeetr/silex).